# I can't access via web to OpenDayLight 11

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded and unziped ODL 11. I entered to the karaf interface and installed some features like:
feature:install odl-restconf (and some others)

After that action I can see (with netstat) the port ipv6:8181 openned.(Before that action the port was not openned) So It's important to install some features to open this web access port.

I access to http://myip:8181/index.html from my browser

But It returned:

HTTP ERROR 401

Problem accessing /index.html. Reason:

```
Unauthorized
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t anything available on `/index.html`. RESTCONF is mounted under `/restconf` and provides access to the config and operational datastores, and you can see that if you have an identifier (see [the ODL wiki](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Restconf) for details).

If you want to see something without knowing an identifier, install the `odl-mdsal-apidocs` feature and open http://localhost:8181/apidoc/explorer/ (replacing `localhost` as appropriate).

Comment: Ok, but does It mean there is no more user Interface like dlux? With topology discover and other visual plugins?

Comment: No, dlux was dropped in Fluorine and later releases, it was no longer maintained.

Comment: If I wanted to deploy an application, for example, to implement mpls, where should i look for? Is there a kind of repository of REST API applications for ODL? So that I could install It and don't have to make It from scratch?